# VectorContainer in ITK

Tags: c++, itk

I came about the `VectorContainer` [here](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1VectorContainer.html).

The description of the class was not clear. Can you kindly clarify what is the purpose of this class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/Numerics_2FourierDescriptors1_8cxx-example.html) might help to clarify.  A `VectorContainer` can be used to store a series of points, and then iterate through them:

Define the container:

```
typedef itk::VectorContainer< unsigned int, PointType >  PointsContainer;
PointsContainer::Pointer points = PointsContainer::New();
unsigned int numberOfPoints = 10;
points->Reserve( numberOfPoints );
```

Iterate through the points:

```
typedef PointsContainer::Iterator PointIterator;
PointIterator pointItr = points->Begin();
PointType point;
for( unsigned int pt=0; pt<numberOfPoints; pt++) {
   point[0] = 10;
   point[1] = 12;
   pointItr.Value() = point;
   ++pointItr;
}
```